# Can I use createStore() from redux inside a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

**Question: Is it possible to use createStore() from redux in a component?
If so, how to do it properly?**

I'm trying to understand react and redux by tranforming this [stopwatch example](https://codepen.io/liammclennan/pen/VxpZzV) to a component-based approach.

The original approach is as follows:

```
let container = Redux.createStore((model = { running: false, time: 0 }, action) => {
  const updates = {
    'START': (model) => Object.assign(model, {running: true}),
    'STOP': (model) => Object.assign(model, {running: false}),
    'TICK': (model) => Object.assign(model, {time: model.time + (model.running ? 1 : 0)})
  };
  return (updates[action.type] || (() => model))(model);
});
```

And

```
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(view(container.getState()),
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};
```

What I get so far is [this](https://codepen.io/jeffhongxiao/pen/ROKxpd), which does not show the counter div.

Note that I'm trying to understand the reasonings behind react and redux, thus avoiding the use of `react-redux` intentionally.

Comment: My project uses `create-react-app` to create the skeleton in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically possible, but that's not how you should do it.

In React, you want the output of `render` method to be only dependent on component's props and state. So what you want to do, is to define a component that expects something outside of it to provide the props, and then make Redux be that provider.
You can read more about it [here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components).
There was another issue with your example: Redux wants the reducer (the method you pass to `createStore`) to **not** mutate the previous state. `Object.assign(state, ...)` does mutate object, so it needs to be changed to `Object.assign({}, state, ...)`. More on that [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

I have a [working snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGWEwj) for you, but I strongly recomment following the official guides :)